# append empty list to empty list in python

Tags: python

```
channel = []
user = []
```

//
let us add new channel name to channel list, **how to do this**

```
channel = [document[],help[],more[]]
```

now append message in document as-
let append user A,B;

```
user.append("A")
user.append("B")
```

now append as-

```
channel = [document[{'A':'hello','B':'hi','A':'are you at work','B':'no'},help[],more[]]
```

but this is not possible *'A':'hello' will be lost.*
**so what to use?**
i am not using database, in flask, so i have to store information in python data structure.

Comment: What is `document[]` supposed to mean? I’m pretty sure that’s a SyntaxError, and if it weren’t, anything that acts like a normal collection would probably raise a `TypeError`

Comment: that the name of list nothing else

Answer (score 1):

(1) This is invalid in python:

```
channel = [document[],help[],more[]]
```

You could do this:

```
channel = {'document':[], 'help':[], 'more':[]}
```

(2) You cannot have duplicate keys in a python dictionary. So you are forced to use a different structure. The nearest to what you want would be a list of tuples:

```
channel = {'document':[('A','hello'), ('B','hi'), ('A','are you at work'), ('B','no')], 'help':[], 'more':[]}
```

You would build up the document list like this:

```
channel['document'].append(('A', 'hello'))
```

and read out of document like this:

```
for user, message in channel["document"]:
    print(user, message)
```